# How do I structure my SQL query to prevent the return of duplicate rows with related data?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need some help with an SQL Query.  I have a database table that has related data with other tables.  When I query the table it returns the duplicate rows for every row of related data i.e.

```
|-------------|           |-------------|           |-------------|
| Cars        |           | Options     |           | Value       |
|-------------|  ------>  |-------------|  ------>  |-------------|
| CarId       |           | OptionsId   |           | ValueId     |
| CarMake     |           | OptionName  |           | CostValue   |
| CarModel    |           | Confirmed   |           | CarId       |
|-------------|           | CarId       |           | OptionsId   |
                          |-------------|           |-------------|
        |
        |
        --------------->  |-------------|
                          | Warranty    |
                          |-------------|
                          | WarrantyId  |
                          | WarrantyType|
                          | CarId       |
                          |-------------|
```

The query that I have made, which was designed in the query builder of SSMS (because of this it is not using aliases and has the 3 stage naming convention, this will be changed) is as follows:

```
SELECT dbo.Cars.CarId, 
       dbo.Cars.Make, 
       dbo.Cars.Model, 
       dbo.Options.OptionName, 
       dbo.Warranty.WarrantyType,
       dbo.Value.CostValue
FROM   dbo.Cars 
       LEFT JOIN dbo.Options ON dbo.Cars.CarId = dbo.Options.CarId 
       LEFT JOIN Value ON Options.OptionsId = Value.OptionsId 
       LEFT JOIN dbo.Warranty on dbo.Cars.CarId = dbo.Warranty.CarId
```

Executing this query as it stands returns my data, however, for cars with multiple options I receive duplicate rows i.e.

```
Id | Make | Model  | Option Name      | Warranty Type | Value  
27 | Ford | Fiesta | Heated Seats     | Static        | 500
27 | Ford | Fiesta | Front Fog Lights | Static        | 400
```

I've been looking around for possible answers to this question and found that the proposed solution is to use the keyword `DISTINCT` or to create a subquery.  I added `DISTINCT` to my query but the same data was returned, probably because the options are both distinct in their own right, I don't know I'm guessing.

I'm happy to use a subquery but not sure how to apply that to my above query code.  All I want to do here is return one single row for each car with the highest option value i.e.

```
27 | Ford | Fiesta | Heated Seats  |  Static  | 500
```

Can anyone help me write this query?  I think I've included everything in this question but if I can offer more, please let me know.

Comment: How do you want present Options and Warranty information in one line? Why you need these JOINs?

Comment: @RodrigoMenezes I think, for the purposes of this question, we could exclude the  warranty table.  I am happy for the data to be displayed as I mentioned above in my closing statement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of joining the table `Value` which gives you multiple rows, 
you must join this query:

```
SELECT 
  dbo.Value.CarId, 
  dbo.Value.OptionsId, 
  MAX(dbo.Value.CostValue) AS CostValue
FROM dbo.Value
GROUP BY dbo.Value.CarId, dbo.Value.OptionsId
```

which you will give you from the table `Value` for each car the option with the max value.
So try this:

```
SELECT dbo.Cars.CarId, 
       dbo.Cars.Make, 
       dbo.Cars.Model, 
       dbo.Options.OptionName, 
       v.CostValue,
       dbo.Warranty.WarrantyType
FROM   dbo.Cars 
       LEFT JOIN dbo.Options ON dbo.Cars.CarId = dbo.Options.CarId 
       INNER JOIN (
                  SELECT 
                  dbo.Value.CarId, 
                  dbo.Value.OptionsId, 
                  MAX(dbo.Value.CostValue) AS CostValue
                  FROM dbo.Value
                  GROUP BY dbo.Value.CarId, dbo.Value.OptionsId  
       ) AS v ON Options.OptionsId = v.OptionsId 
       LEFT JOIN dbo.Warranty on dbo.Cars.CarId = dbo.Warranty.CarId
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try like below by using window function

```
 with cte as(
           SELECT    dbo.Cars.CarId, 
           dbo.Cars.Make, 
           dbo.Cars.Model, 
           dbo.Options.OptionName, 
           Value.CostValue,
           row_number() over(partition by dbo.Cars.CarId, 
           dbo.Cars.Make, 
           dbo.Cars.Model order by Value.CostValue desc) rn   
    FROM   dbo.Cars 
           LEFT JOIN dbo.Options ON dbo.Cars.CarId = dbo.Options.CarId 
           LEFT JOIN Value ON Options.OptionsId = Value.OptionsId 
           LEFT JOIN dbo.Warranty on dbo.Cars.CarId = dbo.Warranty.CarId
          ) select * from cte where rn=1
```